# Unable to find driver for this platform \"ACPI\" MACOSX version: not yet set

Tags: macos, software-update, error

After applying the latest OSX update, I'm unsure which version it was anymore, but I applied it yesterday, on my MacBook Air I get this screen below and am unable to continue in any way. What now?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try starting up from the recovery partition (by holding command-R), in single user mode (by holding command-S), in safe mode (by holding shift), or in Internet recovery mode (by holding option-command-R).

If you already have backups and you can start up from the recovery partition or in Internet recovery mode, try choosing the [Reinstall OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763) option. It downloads an OS X installer and installs it over the current installation, keeping user files and settings in place.

If you can start up from the recovery partition but reinstalling OS X does not work, try to [erase and reinstall OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11273).

If you don't have backups but you can start up from the recovery partition, you can [save a disk image to an external drive with Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1553).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today too, on a Mac Mini Late 2013.
I have many partitions on the only internal hard drive, with a multiboot configuration with macOS 10.9, 10.10, 10.11, 10.12, 10.13.
I suspect this problem has been caused by the update of macOS 10.13.4 to 10.13.6

However, this is how I fixed it:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode:

   - Start the Mac, and as soon as you hear the boot sound, press and hold pressed Option, until you see the boot menu appearing
   - Select the disk named `Recovery-10.9.5` (or whatever macOS version you have)
2. Update the Kernel Extension cache:

   - Start the Terminal (you can find it in the `Utilities` menu)
   - Identify the correct volume by typing

     ```
     mount
     ```

     on the command-line
   - Find the right volume in the list, for me it was:

     ```
     /dev/disk0s2 on /Volumes/Mavericks (hfs, local, journaled)
     ```
   - Change directory to the volume root by typing

     ```
     cd /Volumes/Mavericks
     ```
   - Rebuild the kext cache by typing

     ```
     touch System/Library/Extensions
     kextcache -f -update-volume ./
     ```
3. Reboot your Mac and voilà! Problem fixed!